Prevent Data Exfiltration from DB IDE/Tool
right now I'm using DBeaver CE (desktop), is there any alternative database tool to prevent data exfiltration after user/dba/programmer execute query and the query result cannot be copy or export from DB tool/IDE ? I'm using PostgreSQL
I tried CloudBeaver but the policy/features apply in all user, cannot per database or per user.

Of you have access to data, there're endless ways to save it to a file. In my humble opinion, I don't think this whole path is going to take you anywhere unless hardware itself is highly restricted (kiosk-like environment, security guard searching your cavities for pendrives, that kind of stuff).
